# WinRT: Scroll Listview to item

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I want to scroll my ListView to some item. But I want to trigger scroll from view model. 
The problem is that Scroll of list can be done only in code behind.
The question is how from view model call method in codebehind that scrolls ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases I create event in ViewModel like this:

```
public delegate void FooHandler();
public event FooHandler FooEvent;
```

which I invoke at the right time:

```
FooEvent.Invoke();
```

Then in View i register handler function like this:

```
(DataContext as FooViewModel).FooEvent += OnFooHandler;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Only one question, is it ok from architecture point?

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich I Hope so. Look, it is like DataBinding where view registers to PropertyChanged event.